# tomcat ant build error, can not parse date string

Tags: tomcat9

tried build the tomcat src with ant: version 1.9.15
/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.45-src/build.xml:1025: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.45-src/build.xml:3745: Failed to parse date string 06/10/2021 11:11:45 上午.

Comment: Resolved with: <format property="tstamp.file" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"/>

Answer (score 0):

please build your linux system with english language instead of chinese.ant cannot parse chinese date string.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to build a project developed on a different locale setting,
you will face an error such as "Failed to parse date string ..."

In case of your question, before building a project, you need to set a local setting on a terminal as follows:

```
$ export LANG=C\
$ export LC_TIME=C
```